# How can I plot surface on mplot3d for data like (x,y,z)=(0,0,1),(0,0,2)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**How can I plot surface on mplot3d for data like**

`(x,y,z)=(0,0,1),(0,0,2)......`

I'm currently using mplot3d on python and I have a scatter data like

`(x,y,z) = (0,1,3),(0,8,9),(1,5,24)......`

I tried `ax.scatter(xp,yp,zp)`, then scatter graph can be shown.

But when i try `ax.plot_trisurf(xp,yp,zp)` for all the data, and `plt.show()` then nothing appears on graph.

How can I plot surface graph from this data?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: show what have you tired and what error you are getting?

Comment: i have datas like (0,1,3),(0,8,9),(1,5,24)...... I tried ax.scatter(xp,yp,zp), then scatter graph can be shown, but when i try ax.plot_trisurf(xp,yp,zp) for all the data, and plt.show() then nothing appears on graph. Thank you very much for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you currently have it, `x = (0,1,3)`, `y = (0,8,9)` and `z=(1,5,24)`. I think you actually need to use `zip` on your coordinates:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y,z = zip((0,1,3),(0,8,9),(1,5,24))

print x
# (0, 0, 1)

print y
# (1, 8, 5)

print z
# (3, 9, 24)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]